# Jest setup with TS; Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: jestjs

I am having issues setting up Jest with typescript. I keep getting the same error no matter what settings I change in jest.config.js

Here are my config files

```
//jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  collectCoverage: false,
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>/'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
    '^.+\\.(css|sass|scss)$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js',
    '^.+\\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp|avif|ico|bmp|svg)$/i': `<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js`,

    // Handle module aliases
    // Should also be updated in tsconfig.json
    "@lib/*": ["<rootDir>/app/lib/*"]
  },
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/', '<rootDir>/.next/'],
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
  },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts']
}
```

This is my jest.config.ts file

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'
```

This is my test file:

```
test("auth test", async () => {
  const auth = await authenticate("invaild", "password")
    expect(auth).toBe(false);
  });
```

The error is thrown in the authenicate function from import PocketBase from "pocketbase";

This is the error produced:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

      4 | // This file sets up the connection to the database
      5 |
    > 6 | import PocketBase from "pocketbase";
        | ^
      7 |
      8 | export function DBConnection(): PocketBase {
      9 |   if (process.env.DB_PORT === undefined) {

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1598:14)
```